# aws / hadoop streaming: passing file as argument to streaming mapper

Tags: amazon-ec2, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I'm trying to pass an S3 directory as an argument to an elastic mapreduce streaming job, however it seems EMR is confusing the directory I've passed as an argument with the streaming mapper itself.

i.e. When I run with the following it works fine:

```
  "-mapper","perl sams_to_vcf.pl -ref ./ref_genome.fa -vars-only -no-dups",
```

But if I add in the directory argument:

```
  "-mapper", "perl sams_to_vcf.pl -ref ./ref_genome.fa -vars-only -outdir s3://ht-out/Fd09/combined -no-dups",
```

I get the following:

```
  "LastStateChangeReason": "Streaming mapper doesn't exist: s3:\/\/ht-out\/Fd09\/combined",
```

I'm pretty certain this is a bug in EMR or hadoop, but just in case is there a reason why this shouldn't work?